# Organize content from HTML documents

Tags: html, indexing, cloud, search-engine

Google and co. crawl the web, downloads HTML documents and organize the content.

I want to organize products/offers from different webshops. The webshops use different systems and have different HTML structures.

I want to avoid coding a converter for each webshop and would like organize the content to make the process more simple.

I dont mind using cloud apps and open source projects.

Any suggestions?